# Which JavaScript-based library can be recommended for a carousel-like swipe experience?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, swipe

I'd like to create a carousel-like swipe experience for mobile touch devices based on JavaScript for iOS, Android and WP8 that's easy to use and fulfills all my requirements.

So far I tried these plugins but none of them really convinced me:

- TouchSwipe (Too complicated)
- SwipeView (Has problems if swiped fast)
- iScroll (No WP8 support)

Thus I'm looking for a good JS library which can fullfill these requirements:

- Must be able to swipe all kind of contents, not only images. E.g. I want to be able to pass it an array of `<div>` elements and the plugin should take care of them and make them horizontally swipeable.
- The plugin **must** work for iOS 4.x+, Android 2.2+ and Windows Phone 8.
- It should be as small (in terms of kilobytes) and lightweight as possible.
- It should be performance-optimized. E.g. if I passed 20 div elements with lots of inner content, the library should be smart enough to hide non-visible items and swipe only the divs that matter (the ones that are visible).
- Swiping should be smooth and if the user releases the screen the swiped element should snap to the borders of the parent element so that only 1 element is visible at a time.

Is there a library which can be recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your requirements I can recommend Hammer.js I have used it on a few similar projects and its nice and small only around 3kb minified. Its pretty easy to extended and modify to your exact requirements, as I don't think anything off the shelf will work exactly to what you need.

http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Also a quick note from experience play around with the default settings to get te right sensitivity and motion range that you want.

Comment: Hm, looks very interesting. I like how lightweight it is and it also seems to have a wide support for operating systems, including WP8. Also I love the jQuery plugin. I'll definitely try it out but also keep an eye if someone else posts something better as it seems that hammer.js only provides support for touch gestures but no carousel-like functionality. I'd have to code that on my own then.

Comment: I gave hammer.js a try and I love it. Thanks! :-) The downloadable zip contains a carousel example. You can copy the code 1:1 and it just works. Awesome!